# What is the default keybinding to Close Windows etc Files in Ubuntu 14.04?

Tags: 14.04, shortcut-keys

In OS X, I press CMD-W. In Ubuntu 14.04, I currently do Super-W and select with mouse which icon to close. However, I would like to have a keybinding because I am using Ultrabook with cumbersome touchpad.

---

How can you close a window with a keybinding in Ubuntu 14.04?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F4</kbd>. Hold the <kbd>Super</kbd> key to see a list of commonly used keyboard shortcuts.

Comment: Also `Ctrl` + `q` closes a lot of programs too. Just did a quick test & it worked for Nautilus, Stellarium & Firefox. `Ctrl` + `w` is a handy shortcut in Firefox for closing the tab you're currently on.